# is SESSION var in php are per user?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I work on tutorial that i found about making my first php app.
So i understand that seasion its a way of making global variables but i am stile not sure how it work.

for example:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

/*** set the access level from the sql dba***/
$_SESSION['access_level'] = $row[2];

/*** unset the form token ***/
unset($_SESSION['form_token']);

/*** send user to index page ***/
$location = 'index.php';
```

Now the user will back to the index page with access level var,

but if one more user will enter in the same time to the the index page? 
is the seasion varibles are different per user? or he will get the same access variable (because its global).

thanks for help,

Or

Comment: Also, you might want to look in to mysqli instead of mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session data is (typically) loaded by cookie.  The session is unique to whomever has that session ID, which is determined by the cookie.

Yes, it's unique to each user.  Variable scope means nothing here.  Each request handled by PHP is isolated and has its own global scope (unless you have built your own daemon or something).